# Taking screnshots with Selenium crashes after a while

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Selenium to take screenshots of whole pages with this code

```
    body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
    driver.set_window_size(1920, body.size['height'])
    screenshot = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
```

after a while I always got this error:

> selenium.common.exeptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
> session deleted because of page crash from unknown error: cannot
> determine loading status from tab crashed
> (Session info: headless chrome=85.0.4138.83)

Is there any way to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: first you could use `print()` before every line of code - to see which line makes problem - maybe it crush on `set_window_size()` or on `find_element_by_tag_name()`. Second: you could check error message in Google - maybe someone already had this problem with screenshot on chrome 85.0.4138.83

Comment: you could create minimal working code which your problem. And then we can run it and test problem. We can also see how you run it - ie. with `headless`, some `options`, etc which can makes problem.